# Set toggle rate in Quartus II

Tags: fpga, intel-fpga, quartus-ii

According to [this document](http://www.altera.co.uk/literature/an/an466.pdf), I need to:

```
 assign 0 MHz toggle rate to Toggle Rate assignments for the pin in the Assignment Editor
```

to place a non-differential pin close to a differential one. However, when in the Assignment Editor, I cannot find "Toggle Rate" as an appropriate Assignment Name. (There is a long list of possible assignments, but none is called "Toggle Rate".)

How can I assign the toggle rate in Quartus II?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the main menu (File|Edit|etc.) choose `Assignments->Assignment Editor` (or simply `Ctrl+Shift+A`).

A window/tab with the assignments will open.  In there you can add the assignment that you want, which in this case is `I/O Maximum Toggle Rate` for the related pin.

The drop-down list under `Assignment Name` is long and alphabetically ordered, and since the option you are looking for starts with `I` instead of the more logical `T`, it is easy to miss.

[image]

Comment: I found the "Power Toggle Rate", but not "I/O Maximum Toggle Rate". Thanks.